# Why nginx server doesn't answer with files?

Tags: docker, file, nginx, server

I have nginx config:

```
server {
    location / {
    root /www/data;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Files locations.csv and blocks.csv are in /www/data directory.

After building that in docker-compose, and trying to download files by GET method, everytime 404 Error is.
URLS which I use:
`http://docker_nginx-geo_1/blocks.csv http://docker_nginx-geo_1/locations.csv`

Nginx server successfully see the request, but doesn'tfind file.

I tried to change locations, but that doesn't work.

Comment: answer like that:
2023/03/29 13:57:08 [error] 30#30: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/blocks.csv" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.224.3, server: localhost, request: "GET /blocks.csv HTTP/1.1", host: "docker_nginx-geo_1"

Comment: Please don't comment on your own question - just edit the question to add that info.

Comment: That said, since it's using a different root clearly either the file you're looking at isn't loaded at all by nginx or the request is hitting a server block that is different from the one in the question. Try `nginx -T` (capital T) inside the container and look for which server blocks exist - if you don't immediately see the problem please add the whole output to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's related to another `.conf` file in this directory `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` because in nginx.conf this directory included.

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

You can comment this line or remove that `.conf` file then everything works.

```
rm -f /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf
```